# Controling icons/text shown using CSS classes

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a div with contents that can be styles as *info* or *warning* as shown below. (The underscore is for deactivating the impact of the class for **this particular example case** and needs not to be addressed in this scope.)

```
<div className="content info _warning">
  ...
  <div className="footer">
    <i className="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

By switching over to

```
<div className="content _info warning">
  ...
</div>
```

I'm controlling the color of the icon at the bottom, as set up by the following styling.

```
div.content.warning div.footer { ...
  color: burlywood;
}

div.content.info div.footer { ...
  background-color: fuchsia;
}
```

The problem is that I'd like the icon to change as well. If I'd be using images, I'd hide all by the needed one but that against using the vectorizable FontAwesome goodies. I considered a set of divs with different contents as shown below but it seems clunky.

...

Is there a CSS based approach that can be used to alter the icon shown in the pseudo-code below?

```
div.content.warning div.footer { ...
  color: burlywood;
  image: "fas fa-warning";
}

div.content.info div.footer { ...
  background-color: fuchsia;
  image: "fas fa-info";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using FontAwesome icons, you should keep using fa-* classes on different elements and hide them accordingly with your custom classes. This is what I mean:

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="info-message">
    <i class="fa-info-icon"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="warning-message">
    <i class="fa-warning-icon"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```css
.footer .info-message,
.footer .warning-message {
  display: none;
}

.footer.info .info-message {
  display: block;
}

.footer.warning .warning-message {
  display: block;
}
```

So the proper icon element will be shown just giving .info or .warning on footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :after pseudo selector in CSS for example:

```
div.content.warning div.footer:after { ...
  content: "(Icon with .warning styles)"
}

div.content.info div.footer:after { ...
  content: "(Icon without .warning styles)"
```

}

if you're using Font Awesome you can dynamically add the content property through Javascript

Comment: That renders the string verbatim mode - I'd like it to render HTML so I can use *<i class='fas fa-info></i>*. Any hints on this?

Comment: What you can do is use unicode Font Awesome characters - check out https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io
Now add font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; to your :after psuedo class and a font-weight of 900.
I'm not positive about the rendering of HTML but that is a work around
Check out this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXpYxd